# When i use replace mesh logic NODE not brick the mesh boundaries dont update

Tags: game-engine

Im haveing an issue when using the replace mesh node not brick. Iv done triangle mesh and checked the box for it in the node. The mesh dose replace corectly, but it still has the hit box of the original object that was replaced. Its a bummer. Im using upbge 0.36.1

Comment: I'm sorry, this site is about problems using and the addons that come officially with Blender. For external, please contact the developers about any issues.

Comment: Hello, Gordon, at last reference, we are still prepared to handle upbge questions here, although our range of expertise might not be that extensive. See, e.g. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3056/35559

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Do either of you have any information on the question posed as it has been deemed okay to be asked in this form.